# Access JNI Object to Java layer as reference pointer

Tags: java, android, c++, pointers, java-native-interface

I'm writing an application where I have lot to do with `JNI` call and every-time I have to perform `getter()` call to access variable values. Instead is it possible to access **Object reference** of `JNI` object on Java Layer so can get updated variable value just by variable name (like `obj.name` instead `obj.getName()`).

I have check with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1632367/2624806) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23996746/2624806), but not getting way how to covert address to Object at java layer.

**EDIT**
I wanted to access Obj this way at Java layer from JNI.

```
private native CustomObj getCPPCustomObjectPointer();
```

Any suggestion here.

Comment: You should be able to make a Java class with `native` methods for JNI access.  Why don't you post the code you have right now so the community can take a look at it and figure out what the best way forward is?

Comment: [This](http://elliotth.blogspot.in/2007/03/optimizing-jni-array-access.html) I followed to set object from Java-JNI but how to access from JNI-Java as an pointer Object so can access class-object variable by name. This is where I stuck.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Kris, I don't know how to get object from JNI to Java, this is where I stuck. I have update what Im expecting from JNI layer. Please follow.

Comment: This might be useful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327773/android-jni-get-two-fields-from-java-class  The Oracle Java documentation for accessing object fields is here:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp16536

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks, but in my case I wanted to access object like class/struct access from JNI to Java layer. Any suggestion here!

Comment: @Shubh Like this?  http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/field.html

Comment: @AndrewHenle This is again to access Java layer variable to JNI but what about JNI-variable to Java layer. Am I missing anything here u wanted to explain! Also I wanted to access Class-structure object instead individual variable.

Comment: If you want to map native objects to java objects, you need to use jna: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179833/how-do-i-call-c-c-code-from-android-using-jna

Comment: @DenisTulskiy That's one alternative. It isn't the only one.

Comment: @EJP what are other option and fast as JNI at least as I have lot to do with JNI layer per second basis.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks, now I got your point. I am getting **JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: field operation on invalid global reference: 0xa** ..any time you faced similar problem?

Comment: May be this video holds the answer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7MIUVo-sHcM&index=2&list=PL25m8eyiFUJjNGoObid-BG-bPh66DOEXH

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to access Object reference of JNI object on Java Layer?

Yes, you can. However you cannot use it for accessing its properties. You are only able to hold its address as a `long` value.

If you would like to do so, you should create your C++ objects in heap memory and return their addresses as `long` numbers.

```
MyClass *obj = new MyClass();
return (long) obj;
```

In Java side you can save that address as a `long` number wherever you want. Since objects have been created in heap memory, they will remain valid between JNI calls.

Also, you have to pass them to later JNI calls as a `long` number and then you should cast them to `MyClass *` in your C++ side.

```
MyClass *obj = (MyClass *)thatLongNumber;
obj->someProperty; // Access its properties and methods via -> operator
```

Comment: Thanks..about to hold address as long, I'm aware but as no use if can not access property. Can we have some pseudo code to access property via  JNI-> Java -> JNI(access property).

Comment: I couldn't understand what you mean by _"JNI-> Java -> JNI(access property)"_. If you would want to access properties/fields of a C++ object (which its address as a `long` number is already known at Java side), AFAIK, you cannot do this at _Java_ side but you can do at _C++_ side.

Comment: I mean ..get address from JNI to JAVA and Now take same address from Java to JNI to read object property as pointer reference. I'm stuck how to create object via this 'long' address at JNI layer.

Comment: @Shubh Simply by casting it. `MyClass *obj = (MyClass *)thatLongNumber;`

Answer (score 0):

You want to retain a reference **to a C++** object **from your Java** side? **you can't**.

Those implementations (C/Java) for representing and accessing objects/primitives are completely different.
That's why there's so much [mambo jambo functions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html) when you you cast from one data type to another.